# On adding fixed effects

Tags: applied-econometrics, fixed-effects

Let $Y_{ijst}$ be some outcome variable of firm $i$ of industry $j$, located in state $s$, at time $t$. Normally, if we want to run any differences-in-differences specification where treatment varies across firms $i$ and time $t$, I would throw in firm fixed effects $\lambda_i$ and time fixed effects $\tau_t$ in my regression specification, and then, the coefficient of my treatment variable $x_{it}$ will give me causal effect of $x_{it}$ on outcome $Y_{ijst}$.

Suppose instead of $x_{it}$, my regressor of interest is the following interaction term: $z_{st}*w_j$: something which varies across state x time ($s$ and $t$) and the other which varies across industries ($j$). Then, in this specification, does the ad-hoc addition of fixed effects - firm fixed effects ($\lambda_i$, which subsumes industry and state fixed effects) and time fixed effects ($\tau_t$) work for identification of causal effect? Or shall I also include other fixed effects - state-time, industry-time, state-industry? Mainly asking because my coefficient turns insignificant once I add the last two.

Comment: Just to clarify, the $y$ variable in $x_{it}=z_{st}\cdot y_{j}$ is not the outcome variable $Y$, correct?

Comment: Outcome variable is still $Y_{ijst}$. Just changing the independent variable from $x_{it}$ to $z_{st}*w_j$. I might have confused you with $y_j$ being the interaction. Sorry that was an error. I have made the right edit now. Thanks.

Comment: Is $w_j$ a categorical variable? If so, you could just create a series of interactions $z_{st} \cdot 1(w_j=1)$ ... $z_{st} \cdot 1(w_j=W)$, where $1(w_j = a)$ is an indicator variable for when $w_j=a$.

Comment: $w_j$ is a continuous variables. Do I need to add the additional fixed effects mentioned in the question?